# Why these tensor fields do not depend on the hypersurfaces chosen to define them?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

In the paper [Dynamics of Extended Bodies in General Relativity. I. Momentum and Angular Momentum](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2416466), W.G. Dixon proposes definitions for momentum and angular momentum of a certain distribution of matter in GR described by an energy momentum tensor $T$ and a current one-form $J$ on spacetime $(M,g)$.

Essentialy, he defines $W = \operatorname{supp}T\cup \operatorname{supp}J$ as the so-called "world tube" of the matter and supposes that: if $\Sigma \subset M$ is one spacelike hypersurface such that $W\cap \Sigma\neq \emptyset$ then there is one open set $N_\Sigma\subset M$ such that $W\cap \Sigma\subset N_\Sigma$ and $N_\Sigma$ is a normal neighborhood of all its points.

Under these conditions he defines:

$$p^{\kappa}(z,\Sigma)=\int_\Sigma (K^\kappa_\alpha(x,z)\mathfrak{T}^{\alpha\beta}(x)+\Psi^{\kappa}(x,z)\mathfrak{J}^{\beta}(x))n_\beta(x)d^{n-1}x$$

$$S^{\kappa\lambda}(z,\Sigma)=2\int_\Sigma \sigma^{[\lambda}(H^{\kappa]}_\alpha(z,x)\mathfrak{T}^{\alpha\beta}(x)+\Phi^{\kappa]}(x)\mathfrak{J}^\beta(x))n_\beta(x)d^{n-1}x$$

where $\Sigma\subset M$ is a spacelike hypersurface, $n$ is its normal vector, with $z\in \Sigma\cap W \neq \emptyset$. Also $K^{\kappa}_\alpha$, $H^\kappa_\alpha$, $\Psi^\kappa$, $\Phi^\kappa$ are two-point tensors whose definitions don't really seem to matter here.

The issue is that he derives that on maximally symmetric spacetimes (those with constant curvature), given a one-paramter family of hypersurfaces $\Sigma(s)$, $s\in (a,b)$ and a path $\gamma : (a,b)\to M$ with $\gamma(s)\in \Sigma(s)$ the tensor fields over $\gamma$ defined by

$$p^{\kappa}(s)=p^{\kappa}(\gamma(s),\Sigma(s)),\quad S^{\kappa \lambda}(s)=S^{\kappa\lambda}(\gamma(s),\Sigma(s))$$

satisfy the differential equations (with $k$ the constant curvature)

$$\dfrac{D}{ds}p^{\kappa}=k S^{\kappa\lambda}\dot{\gamma}_{\lambda},\quad \dfrac{D}{ds}S^{\kappa\lambda}=2p^{[\kappa}\dot{\gamma}^{\lambda]}.$$

Now the author of the paper says in his words:

> The pair of equations (5.7) and (5.9) [those above] can now be integrated along $L$ given the values of $p^\kappa$ and $S^{\kappa\lambda}$ at one point of it. This shows that $p^{\kappa}$ and $S^{\kappa\lambda}$ must be independent of the particular choice of $\Sigma$, depending only on the point $z$ at which they are evaluated. They are thus well defined tensor fields on $M$.

Now I can't understand. He says that those equations implies that the definitions he gave are actually independent of $\Sigma$, i.e., $p^{\kappa}(z,\Sigma)=p^{\kappa}(z,\Sigma')$ and $S^{\kappa\lambda}(z,\Sigma)=S^{\kappa\lambda}(z,\Sigma')$ for distinct $\Sigma,\Sigma'$ with $z\in \Sigma\cap \Sigma'\cap W$.

How to understand what the auhtor says? Why these equations implies independence of $\Sigma$? I thought that it is because if I pick the same curve with two choices of $\Sigma,\Sigma'$, the differential equation is the same, but if I pick another curve connecting two points, why would it be the same, for example?

What really is the point here that solving this equation on the curve implies indepdence of $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is the uniqueness theorem for ODEs: along any curve $\gamma(s)$ starting at $x_0$ we know that $X(s) = (p(\gamma(s)),S(\gamma(s)))$ satisfies some first-order linear ODE system $X'(s) = L(s) X(s)$, and thus $X$ is determined along the whole curve by its value at $x_0$. Since any point can be connected to $x_0$ by some curve, we can thus determine $p$ and $S$ everywhere by knowing their values at the single point $x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AnthonyCarapetis. I thought on something like this but something confused me: what if we pick two different curves joining two points defined on two different intervals? Why in that case the result should be the same in both of them?

Comment: You can always rescale the parametrizations to be on the same interval. The fields are not *defined* as solutions along curves - once we fix a family of surfaces they are already defined on some large set, and just also happen to solve the ODE along every curve. Thus of course the result at the endpoint must be the same - it's just (e.g.) $p(\gamma(1),\Sigma(1))$.

Comment: that we can change the parametrization to bring everything to the same interval is fine, but the equations depends on the tangent vector, so changing the curves gives another equation isn't it? What am I missing?

Comment: @user1620696: the point is that we already know that the solution of the ODE is path-independent, since we originally defined $p,S$ without reference to the curve (i.e. in terms of $\Sigma(s)$ alone).

Comment: that's true. It all follows from the fact that $p,S$ are already defined in some region as you said. Thanks for the help !